# How do you teleport to a private server using TeleportPartyAsync() in ROBLOX?

Tags: lua, roblox

I wanted it to teleport to a private server but it wont teleport and it doesn't show any errors.

Here's the code:

```
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService")
local Players = {}
local GamePlayers = game:GetService("Players")
local IsTeleporting = false
local PlayersAllowed = script.Parent.Lobby.Teleporter.MaxPlayers

local function Teleport()
    if #Players > 0 then
        local TeleportPlayers = {}

        for i = 1, #Players do
            local I = i
            if game.Players:FindFirstChild(Players[i]) then
                table.insert(TeleportPlayers, GamePlayers:FindFirstChild(Players[i]))
                TransitionEvent:FireClient(GamePlayers:FindFirstChild(Players[i]))
            else
                table.remove(Players, i)
            end
        end
        wait(0.5)
        IsTeleporting = true
        pcall(function()
            TeleportService:TeleportPartyAsync(TeleportID, TeleportPlayers)
        end)
        
        
        wait(0.5)
        IsTeleporting = false
    end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you think `pcall` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it doesn't show any errors.

```
pcall(function()
   print("function called")
   error("an error occurred!")
   print("this will not be reached")
end)
```

This will print `"function called"`. Nothing else. No error shown.

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-pcall):

> **pcall (f [, arg1, ···])**
>
> Calls the function f with the given arguments in protected mode. This
> means that any error inside f is not propagated; instead, pcall
> catches the error and returns a status code. Its first result is the
> status code (a boolean), which is true if the call succeeds without
> errors. In such case, pcall also returns all results from the call,
> after this first result. In case of any error, pcall returns false
> plus the error object. Note that errors caught by pcall do not call a
> message handler.

Check pcall's return values to see if the function ran successfully.

Compare your code to [Roblox's example](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/TeleportService/TeleportPartyAsync):

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService")
 
local placeId = 0 -- replace
local playerList = Players:GetPlayers()
 
local success, result = pcall(function()
    return TeleportService:TeleportPartyAsync(placeId, playerList)
end)
 
if success then
    local jobId = result
    print("Players teleported to "..jobId)
else
    warn(result)
end
```